# Invoking another Java GUI program in a loop at a particular condition

Tags: java, multithreading, matlab

I have developed a program in which I am running a loop in Java as follows.

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if(i==2)
    {
        call A GUI of another program (written in JAVA)
        sleep(20000); // make it sleep for 20 sec.
    }

    // calling a MATLAB file, which itself passing some parameters to a software PowerWorld
}
```

The issue that the program invokes the GUI program only after running all its 10 instances, not after when `i = 2`. I want to perform some other actions available in  Java GUI program. I have tried with calling a separate thread (Java multithreading) when `i = 2`.

```
if (i==2)
{  
    MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable(10);
    Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
    t.start();                  
    try { 
        Thread.sleep(20000); 
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException ie) { }     
}
```

And created a new MyRunnable class as:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int var;
    public MyRunnable(int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public void run() {
        String[] args = {};
        guiprog2.main(args); //A GUI of Program2 that needs to be invoked
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On what thread are you running the loop? The other gui program is running in the same process as the calling process. Assuming both are rendering on the same thread, the second program will not be able to render if you loop is running on the rendering thread. Why not run guiprog2 in a separate process?